# Как сохранить значение переменной в контроллере laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, framework

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой в Laravel. Обращаясь к некоторой функции через Route, я делаю запрос к БД и пытаюсь сохранить ответ в переменную этого же класса `$this->response = DB::select('select * from ...')`, после этого при следующем обращении к этой функции мне бы хотелось написать проверку, что эта переменная не null, но при новом обращении, переменная всегда null, данные не сохранились. Как можно решить данный вопрос?

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    public $response = null;

    public function get_all_user_proposal(){
        if (!is_null($this->response)){
        return 1;
    }

    $this->response = DB::select('select * from ......');

    return json_encode($this->response);
}
```

Comment: Смотри в сторону ViewComposer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сохранить переменную в БД или сессию и сверять полученное значение с сохранённым.

Хотя если, как Вы говорите, результат большой, есть смысл посмотреть в сторону чего-нибудь из разряда Memcached или Redis.

Comment: Я специально хочу сохранить запрос из бд куда-нибудь в переменную, чтобы снова не обращаться к бд, потому что запрос может быть довольно большой. Считаю, что сохранять в БД не рационально. как и в сессию, потому что мне не нужны эти данные на остальных страницах, а только лишь на одной

Comment: Ну, так и используйте их на одной. Просто обычно при каждом обращении создаётся новый экземпляр контроллера и поэтому сохранять что-либо в его поля бесполезно.

Comment: Хорошо, я вас понял. То есть сохранять в сессию вы считаете лучшим вариантом в данной ситуации, да?

Comment: Либо БД, либо сессия. Хотя если, как Вы говорите, результат большой, есть смысл посмотреть в сторону чего-нибудь из разряда Memcached или Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из задачи вам нужно использовать паттерн синглтон.
Если из роута вызываете метод `get_all_user_proposal` и далее при последующем обращении к нему вам должно возвращаться уже полученное ранее значение, возможна следующая реализация...

Надеюсь я вас правильно понял:

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    public $response = null;

    public function get_all_user_proposal ()
    {
        if (!$this->response)
        {
            $this->response = DB::select('select * from ......');
        }

        return json_encode($this->response);
    }
}
```

Такая реализация позволит вам **1 раз делать запрос к БД**, последующие обращения вы будете получать значение из свойства `$this->response`

Comment: Это не сработает, так как при каждом обращении к функции класса в ларавель, создастся его новый экземпляр

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй такой способ, через статический вызов, он не требует создания экземпляра:

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    private static $response = null;

    public static function get_all_user_proposal()
    {
        if (!self::$response)
        {
            self::$response = DB::select('select * from ......');
        }

        return json_encode(self::$response);
    }
}
```

Вызов: `MyClass::get_all_user_proposal();`

"*после этого при следующем обращении к этой функции мне бы хотелось написать проверку, что эта переменная не null*" - я понял что вам в рамках одного запроса к PHP необходимо обращаться с разных частей кода к этому методу.

Если же вы имели в виду сохранение состояние свойства до следующего запуска PHP то это кэширование, альтернативы много. (В том же ларавеле)